# EasyApache4 updates overwriting htaccess files

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, cpanel, easyapache-4

I recently upgraded my cPanel server to EasyApache4 and all is working well until recently when an EasyApache4 auto-update caused the PHP config `AddHandler` in all of my `.htaccess` files (3 of them) to all be over written with a default configuration causing my websites to break.  I fixed everything, and then it just happened again last night.  How can I set/configure things so the server still gets the auto-updates but doesn't overwrite/reset components of the htaccess files?  Or at least adds the .html extension back to the PHP `Addhandler`.

Specifically this:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .html .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Is being defaulted back to this (removing the .html extension) after the updates:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I am running into it as well.

Comment: @AlmostPitt -  I did, I copied the handler to before of the `<IfModule mime_module>`, If anything in the `<IfModule...>` gets defaulted or changed, the copied one will stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue also.

I move my custom AddHandler out of the cPanel comments

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
....
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I manually change the PHP version by MultiPHP, all contents within the comments are changed to default setting but my custom AddHandler still remain unchanged. At last there are two AddHandler in .htaccess, not sure whether any potential issue.